# uncaught typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, this

here is part of my function code that makes an error on javascript error console ( Google Chrome)

```
function premuto(x){
        if(x.Clickable){
                x.Selected = !x.Selected;
            if (x.Selected){
                x.style.backgroundColor ='lightblue';
                y = document.getElementById('spazio');
                y.innerHTML = y.innerHTML + x.innerHTML;
                sequenza[indice] = x.Number;
                indice++;
            }
```

error compares at line "sequenza[indice] = x.Number;"

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the variable "sequenza" declared?

Comment: And where is it initialized?

Comment: var sequenza;  Do I need initialized it?

Comment: @RandomAccessMemory: Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `indice` is 0 and `sequenza` is `undefined`. In javascript it always raises a type error, if you try to reach undefined variable's properties or methods. You should debug your code and see exactly when sequanza becomes `undefined`.